# left join returns no result

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

To my understanding, left join returns the results of the left table even though there is no connections. So, I am expecting the result to show the left table, however, there was no result shown on my query.

Please note that I have 9 common columns that is why I join all of those columns. However, `userId`, `universal_id`, `ps_project_id`, `ps_campaign_id` all contains no data. From what I understand, even if those 4 columns does not contain data and cant be join, it should returns some rows that contain data on other joined columns right? What am I missing here?

This is my query:

```
select 
    c.pagepath,
    a.medium,
    a.source,
    count(*) as count_pageviews
 
from `traffic` as a

left outer join `hits_page` as c
 on a.fullVisitorId = c.fullVisitorId 
 and a.visitId = c.visitId 
 and a.userId = c.userId
 and a.universal_id = c.universal_id
 and a.ps_project_id = c.ps_project_id
 and a.ps_campaign_id = c.ps_campaign_id
 and a.visitStartTime = c.visitStartTime 
 and a.date = c.date
 and a.visitNumber = c.visitNumber

left outer join `hits_sample` as d
 on a.fullVisitorId = d.fullVisitorId 
 and a.visitId = d.visitId 
 and a.userId = d.userId
 and a.universal_id = d.universal_id
 and a.ps_project_id = d.ps_project_id
 and a.ps_campaign_id = d.ps_campaign_id
 and a.visitStartTime = d.visitStartTime 
 and a.date = d.date
 and a.visitNumber = d.visitNumber

where c.pagepath = "/sellland"
and d.type = "PAGE"
 
group by 1,2,3
 
order by count_pageviews desc
```

Comment: `and d.type = "PAGE"` in your where clause turns this into an inner join.  Move it to the ON clause.

Comment: Same issue with `where c.pagepath = "/sellland"`.

Comment: Thank you so much, guys! It works as intended now :D

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Andrew and Richard on the comment section, I have made adjustments to the code, and it works now.

The code:

```
    select 
    c.pagepath,
    a.medium,
    a.source,
    count(*) as count_pageviews
 
from `traffic` as a

left outer join `hits_page` as c
 on a.fullVisitorId = c.fullVisitorId 
 and a.visitId = c.visitId 
 and a.userId = c.userId
 and a.universal_id = c.universal_id
 and a.ps_project_id = c.ps_project_id
 and a.ps_campaign_id = c.ps_campaign_id
 and a.visitStartTime = c.visitStartTime 
 and a.date = c.date
 and a.visitNumber = c.visitNumber
 and c.pagepath = "/sellland"
 


left outer join `hits_sample` as d
 on a.fullVisitorId = d.fullVisitorId 
 and a.visitId = d.visitId 
 and a.userId = d.userId
 and a.universal_id = d.universal_id
 and a.ps_project_id = d.ps_project_id
 and a.ps_campaign_id = d.ps_campaign_id
 and a.visitStartTime = d.visitStartTime 
 and a.date = d.date
 and a.visitNumber = d.visitNumber
 and d.type = "PAGE"


group by 1,2,3
 
order by count_pageviews desc
```